# Creating an array of a specific size from data in an array of a larger size - averages

Tags: matlab

I want to find the average value across an array between the element(x) and element(x+1)

```
 for val = 1: xMid_p-1
     eapDia_p = diaArray_p(1,val);
     baseDia_p = diaArray_p(1,end);
     curDiaArray_p = linspace(eapDia_p, baseDia_p, xMid_p-1);
     curRadArray_p = curDiaArray_p/2;
     maxRad = max(curRadArray_p);

     for val = 1 : xMid_p-1
         ln(1,val) = maxRad(:) - curRadArray_p(val);
         lnE(1,val) = ln(1,val).^3;
         presAn(1,val)= acos(((refDia_p/2)*cos(refPresAng_p))./curRadArray_p(val));
         arcToo(1,val) = 2 * curRadArray_p(val)*((twRefDia_p/refDia_p)+(tan(refPresAng_p)-refPresAng_p)-(tan(presAn(1,val))-presAn(1,val)));
         chor(1,val) = 2 * curRadArray_p(val) * sin(arcToo(1,val)/(curRadArray_p(1,val)*2));

         for val =  1 : xMid_p - 2
             lnM(1,val) = maxRad(:) - curRadArray_p(val);
             lnME(1,val)=lnM(1,val).^3;

         end

     end 

      lnCubed(1,:) = ln.^3;
      lnMCubed(1,:) = lnM.^3;
      lnEq = lnCubed(2:end) - lnMCubed;

 end
```

please see chor(1,val), this would give the value :

```
 chor =
      1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
```

I want to find the average chor, therefore the array will be one element smaller in size and will give the result

```
 aveChor =
     1.5    2.5   3.5    4.5    5.5    6.5   7.5
```

Comment: A couple of sensible answers already so I'll just add - you could vectorise this code.  A lot. For a start, `for val =  1 : xMid_p - 2` loop is unnecessary and then because there's another loop around it you'll be overwriting with the same values.

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `indexing` -

```
aveChor = (chor(2:end) + [chor(1:end-1)])/2
```

Another approach using `diff` -

```
aveChor = (2*chor(1:end-1) + diff(chor))/2
```